# Foreign key not updated (configured with required principal-dependent)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Fluent API config:

```
internal class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
    {
        public UserMap()
        {
            Property(x => x.CSL).IsRequired();

            //relational properties
            HasRequired(x => x.UserType).WithMany(x => x.Users).HasForeignKey(x => x.UserType_ID).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
            HasRequired(x => x.TimelineVolumetry).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.User).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);           
        }
    }

internal class TimelineVolumetryMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<TimelineVolumetry>
    {
        public TimelineVolumetryMap()
        {
            Property(x => x.AllowedWeeks).IsRequired();

            //relational properties
            HasRequired(x => x.User).WithRequiredDependent(x => x.TimelineVolumetry).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        }
    }
```

Insert query:

```
User u = new User();
u.CSL = csl;
u.UserType_ID = role;
u.TimelineVolumetry = new TimelineVolumetry();
u.TimelineVolumetry.User = u;
ctx.User.Add(u);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

After inserting a user in the database I get `User_ID = 0` for `TimelineVolumetry`. Is there a way to auto set the `User_ID` when adding a user or am I forced to save the `TimelineVolumetry` again after setting the foreign key?

```
public class TimelineVolumetry
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int AllowedWeeks { get; set; }

        //relational properties
        public int User_ID { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }

        public TimelineVolumetry()
        {
            AllowedWeeks = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some points that can be improved in the configuration of your relationships. First, you don't need to configure the relationship between `User` and `TimelineVolumetry` twice, with one is enough. Also you don't need to configure the relationships with cascade delete. If the foreign key on the dependent entity is not nullable (like your case), then Code First sets cascade delete on the relationship, so is already set it.

```
public class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Property(x => x.CSL).IsRequired();

        //relational properties
        HasRequired(x => x.UserType).WithMany(x => x.Users).HasForeignKey(x => x.UserType_ID);
        HasRequired(x => x.TimelineVolumetry).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.User);           
    }
}

public class TimelineVolumetryMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<TimelineVolumetry>
{
    public TimelineVolumetryMap()
    {
        Property(x => x.AllowedWeeks).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

About the insert, if you are creating both entities at the same time, you should do this:

```
User u = new User();
//...
var tv= new TimelineVolumetry();
//set required properties of TimelineVolumetry entity
u.TimelineVolumetry =tv;
//u.TimelineVolumetry.User = u;// you don't need to do this
//...
ctx.User.Add(u);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

That will insert both entities properly in the DB(including the value of the foreign key column).

### Update

I am afraid what you want is not possible.You can't create a one-to-one relation with a FK that is not declared as a PK, Entity Framework requires the primary key of the dependent also be the foreign key, so, to achieve what you want, you could do something like this:

```
public class TimelineVolumetry
{
    public int AllowedWeeks { get; set; }

    //relational properties
    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public int User_ID { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public TimelineVolumetry()
    {
        AllowedWeeks = 0;
    }
}
```

That is using Data Annotations, but using  Fluent Api it would be this way:

```
// Configure User_Id as PK for TimelineVolumetry
    modelBuilder.Entity<TimelineVolumetry>()
        .HasKey(e => e.User_Id);

  // Configure User_Id as FK for TimelineVolumetry
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasOptional(s => s.TimelineVolumetry) // Mark TimelineVolumetry is optional for User
                .WithRequired(ad => ad.User); // Create inverse relationship
```

If you want to read more about this subject I recommend you this [link](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx).

Comment: still getting 0 for the foreign key.

Comment: but that value is from the `TimelineVolumetries` Table in DB or a FK property in `TimelineVolumetry` entity?

Comment: Can you show the `TimelineVolumetry` entity to see what properties have?